# Javascript quiz, right or wrong answer colour displaying when clicked

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

Is there a way I can display right or wrong questions on a javascript quiz as a colour when clicked as in right (green) and wrong (red)

So when you click on the answer I would like it to  display a colour when clicked which is either green (right answer) or red (wrong answer)

Oh and the click to restart button does not work rn

And the quiz runs on lives if u get 3 wrong u lose (1 wrong question = 1 life lost)

Hope someone can help thanks

Here is the code linked below

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/theholyduck/pen/PoNqZMd?editors=1111)

Here is my code as-well

```js
// This initialises a request to the trivia database API
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&category=21&difficulty=easy&type=multiple";
var score = 0;
var livesTaken = 0;
var question;
var type;
var correctAnswer;
var incorrect1;
var incorrect2;
var incorrect3;

// This requests the data
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
var jsondata = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
getData(jsondata);
}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

// This function is used to extract the received data
function getData(data) {
// This is the question:
question = data.results[0].question;

// This is the question type eg. multiple choice
type = data.results[0].type;

// This is the correct answer
correctAnswer = data.results[0].correct_answer;

// These are the three incorrect answers
incorrect1 = data.results[0].incorrect_answers[0];
incorrect2 = data.results[0].incorrect_answers[1];
incorrect3 = data.results[0].incorrect_answers[2];

// randomly select answer and other options and place in array
// then display elements from array on the buttons

var randoms = []; // an array to store unique random numbers
var random;

// loop runs four times...
for(i=0; i < 4; i++){
// generates a random number between 0 and 3
random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
// checks if random number already in array...
while(randoms.includes(random)){
// generates another random number
random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
}
// adds random number to array
randoms.push(random);
}


var options = [];
console.log(randoms);
options[randoms[0]] = correctAnswer;
options[randoms[1]] = incorrect1;
options[randoms[2]] = incorrect2;
options[randoms[3]] = incorrect3;

  
  console.log(options);

// This displays the question and answer options

document.getElementById("trivia").innerHTML = question;
  
  for(i=0; i < options.length; i++){
    document.getElementById("trivia").innerHTML += "<br><button onclick='checkAnswer(\""+options[i]+"\")'>" + options[i] + "</button>";
  }
}

function checkAnswer(selected){
console.log("User selected: " + selected);
console.log("The correct answer is: " + correctAnswer);
if(selected == correctAnswer){
  score++;
console.log("You got it right!");
  getNewQuestion();
}
else{
  livesTaken ++;
console.log("Sorry, that's incorrect");
  if(livesTaken ==3){
  quizFailed();
  }else{getNewQuestion();}
}
console.log(score)
console.log(livesTaken)
}



function getNewQuestion(){
// This requests the data
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
var jsondata = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
getData(jsondata);
}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
function quizFailed(){
  document.getElementById("trivia").style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById("endingText").innerHTML = "You have run out of lives, you scored " + score + " pretty bad ngl" + "  <button>click to restart</button>"
  
  score = 0;
  livesTaken = 0;
}
```

```css
body{
                font-family: Arial;
            }
            div#test{
                border: 1px solid #5AB029;
                padding: 10px 40px 40px 40px;
                background-color: #E5FCE3;
                border-radius: 3px;
                width: 50%;
            }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Actualquiz.css">
    <title>Sport Quiz (Medium)</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <div id="trivia"></div>
    <div id ="endingText"></div>
    <div id ="score"></div>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the clicked element to the `checkAnswer` function and change the background style property as required.

Note : Here, I used `setTimeout` function to delay loading next question, so that the user can see if their answer is correct or not for few seconds.

```js
// This initialises a request to the trivia database API
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&category=21&difficulty=easy&type=multiple";
var score = 0;
var livesTaken = 0;
var question;
var type;
var correctAnswer;
var incorrect1;
var incorrect2;
var incorrect3;

// This requests the data
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
var jsondata = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
getData(jsondata);
}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

// This function is used to extract the received data
function getData(data) {
// This is the question:
question = data.results[0].question;

// This is the question type eg. multiple choice
type = data.results[0].type;

// This is the correct answer
correctAnswer = data.results[0].correct_answer;

// These are the three incorrect answers
incorrect1 = data.results[0].incorrect_answers[0];
incorrect2 = data.results[0].incorrect_answers[1];
incorrect3 = data.results[0].incorrect_answers[2];

// randomly select answer and other options and place in array
// then display elements from array on the buttons

var randoms = []; // an array to store unique random numbers
var random;

// loop runs four times...
for(i=0; i < 4; i++){
// generates a random number between 0 and 3
random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
// checks if random number already in array...
while(randoms.includes(random)){
// generates another random number
random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
}
// adds random number to array
randoms.push(random);
}


var options = [];
console.log(randoms);
options[randoms[0]] = correctAnswer;
options[randoms[1]] = incorrect1;
options[randoms[2]] = incorrect2;
options[randoms[3]] = incorrect3;

  
  console.log(options);

// This displays the question and answer options

document.getElementById("trivia").innerHTML = question;
  
  for(i=0; i < options.length; i++){
    document.getElementById("trivia").innerHTML += "<br><button onclick='checkAnswer(\""+options[i]+"\", this)'>" + options[i] + "</button>";
  }
}

function checkAnswer(selected, element){
console.log("User selected: " + selected);
console.log("The correct answer is: " + correctAnswer);
if(selected == correctAnswer){
  score++;
console.log("You got it right!");
element.style.background = "green";
setTimeout(function(){ 
  getNewQuestion();
}, 2000);
  
}
else{
  livesTaken ++;
console.log("Sorry, that's incorrect");
element.style.background = "red";
  if(livesTaken ==3){
  quizFailed();
  }else{
setTimeout(function(){ 
  getNewQuestion();
}, 2000);
  }
}
console.log(score)
console.log(livesTaken)
}



function getNewQuestion(){
// This requests the data
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
var jsondata = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
getData(jsondata);
}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
function quizFailed(){
  document.getElementById("trivia").style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById("endingText").innerHTML = "You have run out of lives, you scored " + score + " pretty bad ngl" + "  <button>click to restart</button>"
  
  score = 0;
  livesTaken = 0;
}
```

```css
body{
                font-family: Arial;
            }
            div#test{
                border: 1px solid #5AB029;
                padding: 10px 40px 40px 40px;
                background-color: #E5FCE3;
                border-radius: 3px;
                width: 50%;
            }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Actualquiz.css">
    <title>Sport Quiz (Medium)</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <div id="trivia"></div>
    <div id ="endingText"></div>
    <div id ="score"></div>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```